# Azure Mobile Service Table Controller and EntityState.Modified

Tags: azure-mobile-services

I am using Azure Mobile Service TableController.
I am having trouble with foreign key relationships in the entity framework. I have two tables: Personsand Countries. Persons has a foreign key column to CountryId.

On save, the entity framework creates a new row in the Countries table with the same name as countries[0], but a new, incremented ID. This is obviously not the desired outcome - the person should have its Country_CountryId field set to the id of countries[0], and a new row should not be created.

How do I solve this?

I am using table controller

```
    // POST tables/Booking
    public async Task<IHttpActionResult> PostPerson(Personitem)
    {
        Person current = await InsertAsync(item);
        return CreatedAtRoute("Tables", new { id = current.Id }, current);
    }
```

I know how to set EntitySate in api controller

```
using (var dt = new DatabaseContext()) { 
    dt.Entities.Add(person);
    dt.Entry(person.Country).State = EntityState.Modified;
    dt.SaveChanges();
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you save that object you should get the country from the database and use it in the person object, something like:

- get country from database "contryIdX"
- set person.ContryId ="contryIdX"
- then save it in database

Comment: Yes, you are right. I should only pass the CountryId instead of Country object.